# Custom Meta Title for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, title

I have several custom post types that need to display different values within `<title></title>` in the header.

I understand for the home page, posts, categories, and pages you can use..

```
if (is_home()){ }
elseif (is_category()){}    
elseif (is_single() ) {}
elseif (is_page() ) {}
```

My question is, how would I do the same for individual CPTs (eg. songs, videos, news..etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template tag to check CPTs single page - [is_singular](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular). So you can use `is_singular('songs')` to check if the current post page is a single page for post type `songs`.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?